# How to snapshot a WKWebView with a transparent background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` with a transparent background and I would like to capture the web contents in an image while preserving the transparency. I haven't been able to get this working with `takeSnapshotWithConfiguration`, `drawViewHierarchyInRect`, or `renderInContext`. I'm thinking it just might not be possible.

This is my code for the `takeSnapshotWithConfiguration` approach:

```
WKSnapshotConfiguration *wkSnapshotConfig = [WKSnapshotConfiguration new];
wkSnapshotConfig.snapshotWidth = [NSNumber numberWithInt:180];

[_webView takeSnapshotWithConfiguration:wkSnapshotConfig completionHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable snapshotImage, NSError * _Nullable error) {
  NSString *tempFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"img.png"];
  NSData *photoData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(snapshotImage);
  [photoData writeToFile:tempFilePath atomically:YES];
}];
```

Comment: In your example `photoData` does not anyhow correspond to the `snapshotImage`.

Comment: @DisableR you're right. Thanks. I had deleted a line by accident when removing all the unnecessary stuff. I've got a whole bunch of code I've been trying for the different ways of saving the image. Fixed it in my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `_webView` *itself* has opacity. So even if the contents displayed contain transparency they are essentially rendered over the view's background.

I was able to capture an [image with transparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bFUx.jpg), of a minimal html with an inline style like this (pardon my html skills :P):

```
body {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I have verified this on iOS 11+ just by setting the `opaque` property to the webview (please note that I didn't set a background color to the webview or its embedded scrollview. If your setup is different I guess you should also set them to clear color):

---

**ObjC**

`_webView.opaque = NO;`

**Swift**

`webView.isOpaque = false`

everything else is exactly like in your setup (`WKSnapshotConfiguration` / `takeSnapshot...`)

Comment: Background in css would be `background:  transparent`.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Thanks. Is there any real difference or just syntactic sugar?

Comment: Not really sure, tbh. More of the latter, I think. 

Comment: I would also prefer `transparent` but I needed to change alpha to `0.5` while testing, that's why I stuck with this :P Thanks though

Comment: I still can't get this to work. It still always captures a white background (even though the webview isn't above a white background). I'm in react-native (with a slightly modified react-native-webview that adds this snapshot method), so maybe there's something there causing an issue...

Comment: The react-native-webview component does this for the background color:

CGFloat alpha = CGColorGetAlpha(backgroundColor.CGColor);
  self.opaque = _webView.opaque = (alpha == 1.0);
  _webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
  _webView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

Comment: Ok, I think this is actually working. I didn't know I could preview the UIImage in the debugger like you showed. It seems that it is working for me... so I'm losing transparency later in the process. Thanks

Comment: @MaxSchmeling Great! Glad that helped you :) Didn't know that react-native was involved but I'm glad you sorted things out.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the return image in a UIImage format, which is by definition able to store alpha channel. But I have no idea how the takeSnapshotWithConfiguration function handles the image data but from the name itself "snapshot" suggests that there will be no transparency and a snapshot always captures everything what you can see on the display. What you can do is change the background color of WebView to Lime color or other color, and then preprocess UIImage to set any pixel that is Lime color to be Alpha 0.

Comment: It doesn't capture the background color because on screen I have a blue color behind the WebView. It captures the transparent part as white. I've thought about doing something like you suggest, but it wouldn't work well for partial transparency.